# Extract with multiple Patterns

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

Having an issue that maybe some help me with.  I am trying to extract two patterns from a string and place them in another column.  It's extracting the first string fine but I am missing some in getting the second one there.  Here's the string.

```py
jobseries['New Column'] = jobseries['Occupation'].str.extract('(GS-\d+)(|)(WG-\d+)').fillna('')
```

The first string is `(GS-\d+)` and the second string is `(WG-\d+)`

I've tried a ton of variations none have worked.

Comment: Include the code in your post

Comment: You should place `r` before the string literal `r'(GS-\d+)(WG-\d+)'`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals. Also, the `(|)` is useless, so just drop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either

```py
jobseries['New Column'] = jobseries['Occupation'].str.extract(r'(GS-\d+|WG-\d+)').fillna('')
```

or a shorter

```py
jobseries['New Column'] = jobseries['Occupation'].str.extract(r'((?:GS|WG-\d+)').fillna('')
```

The points are:

- There must be only one capturing group in the regex since you are using `Series.str.extract` and assignt he result to a single column (`New Column`)
- The regex must match either one string or the other, but you can factor in the beginning of the pattern and simply use `((?:GS|WG-\d+)` instead of `(GS-\d+|WG-\d+)`, that means *a capturing group that matches either `GS` or `WG` and then a hyphen and then one or more digits*.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you so much.  I know I was missing something.  Thanks again!